# LAPACK different outputs when using solvers for banded matricies

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra, lapack, blas

I've been stuck at this for hours and hoping someone can figure out what I am missing. I am solving Ax=B firstly using DGESV which I am 99% sure is correct. Then I am puting A into a banded form and using DGBSV and getting a different output.

Here is my expected inputs and outputs where A is the first 9x9 matrix B is -r 1x9 and x is sk 1x9.
[image: Inputs and Ouputs using DGESV]

And this is what my usage of DGBSV looks like A=JBtemp,B=-r,x=SK:
[[image: Inputs and Ouputs using DGBSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiVTJ.png)

We can see that the x values dont match and here is my code usage of the two functions.

```
call dgesv(n,1,J0,n,ipiv,r,n,info)

call dgbsv(n,KL,KU,1,JBtemp,KU+1+KL+KL,ipiv,r,n,info)
```

Comment: Please follow [mcve]. Those two lines are completely insufficient. We do not even know what the various symbols mean.

Comment: In the last two entries of B in the second case the sign has been reversed - so you are solving a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-problem.

Both results are correct - yes, really! - *for the data that you have given them*. I checked that with Gaussian elimination.

In your B vector (what you label -r) in the first example it ends

```
50.1899...
70.9...
50.19...
```

but in the second example it ends

```
50.1899...
-70.9...
-50.19...
```

Note the change from positive to negative for the last two entries of B.